# LWC - updateRecord(recordInput) on Inline Editing for Multiple Rows Lightning Datatable Not Working

Tags: lightning-web-components

When doing an update on multiple rows with inline editing, I'm always being met with an error. I've utilised the *updateRecord(recordInput)* from this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_inline_edit) to save multiple rows however I keep getting the error shown below. The update to single row from the same document is working in contrast.

[image]

The draft values are being recognized as shown in my DevTools:

[image]

Related: https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/1537

Is this a known issue? What am I doing wrong and how can I get this to work correctly?

Here are my code:

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

@track refreshTable = [];
@track draftValues = [];
@track saveDraftValues = [];

handleSave(event) {

    let draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;

    const recordInputs =  event.detail.draftValues.slice().map(draft => {
        const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
        return { fields };
    });

    console.log('RECORDINPUTS', JSON.stringify(recordInputs));

    const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {

         this.saveDraftValues = [];

         return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
    }).catch(error => {
        // Handle error
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Edit Products" icon-name="standard:opportunity">
         <div class="slds-m-around_large" style="height: 400px;">
            <template if:true={oppLines}> 
                    <c-custom-data-table 
                        key-field="id"
                        data={oppLines}
                        columns={columns}
                        onsave={handleSave}
                        draft-values={saveDraftValues}
                        onvalueselect={handleSelection}                         
                        >
                    </c-custom-data-table>
            </template>
            <template if:true={error}>
                <p>{oppLines.error}</p>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    <div>
        {loadMoreStatus}
    </div>    
</template>
```

Comment: So you gotta do some debugging stepping through the code to find which line throws for you.Clearly it is after your `RECORDINPUTS` console.log. Lastly, at least where i used this, the `Id` in the `fields` HAD to be `Id` not `id`. (Pascal cased)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed  key-field="Id" and it got worked for me.. because JS is case Sensitive.